# Facebook SDK iOS - how to set Application ID dynamically from code?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to set the Facebook's AppId from code, so I can choose to which app to connect to (between 2 apps, one of them is a test app).

Basically I'm looking for an equivalent for Android's SDK call:

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(ACTIVE_APP_ID);
```

I'm aware of the deprecated iOS call:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:ACTIVE_APP_ID];
```

But can't seem to find alternative to it.
I'm using SDK ver 4.22.1. Thanks!

Comment: According to [the Facebook iOS SDK's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.23/class/FBSettings/), `setDefaultAppID:` is **not** deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try :

```
[FBSDKSettings setAppID:ACTIVE_APP_ID];
```

(I am using version 4.29.0 of FBSDK).

Comment: This is not working for me. It continues using the one I added in the plist file. My idea is to change the facebookAppId based on the environment.

Answer (score 3):

FacebookSDK v4.44.1 swift 5 - Set the Facebook App ID used by the SDK:

```
Settings.appID = "YOUR-FACEBOOK-APPLICATION-IDENTIFIER"
Settings.displayName = "YOUR-FACEBOOK-DISPLAY-NAME"
```

That's the way I have managed to set it programmatically and override the default settings at the info.plist file.

Comment: I don't see any access to Settings class in Facebook SDK.